# Text automatically change after a certain time?

Tags: html-table, spreadsheet

[How to make text automatically change after a certain time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753859/how-to-make-text-automatically-change-after-a-certain-time/76280163#76280163)
It's already been in this thread. But it's been 2 years and it doesn't work.

Tried everything, nothing works. Now writes a syntax error. Please help if you can.

Here is my table for https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u11r9uRsp_HFT1UIdOU9hHr7nC9yjKcNnt6Ca6419jE/edit#gid=0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make text automatically change after a certain time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753859/how-to-make-text-automatically-change-after-a-certain-time)